# Split/Delimit a string on the first space/colon using regex

Tags: regex, go

I am trying to split a string using regex. For example:

```
12 13: 14: 15 => One-12, Two-13 , Three-14: 15
```

i am trying to use the following regex:

```
^(?P< one>.*)\\s(?P< two>.*):\\s(?P< three>.*)$
```

So as I see it, "one" should be the value before first "space"(\s) and then until next colon(:) the value should be "two" and everything after that should be "three".

But the output I get is: One-12 13:, Two-14, Three-15

Note: This is Golang type of regex but I guess this is a general Regex problem. Kindly help me out with this one.

Comment: Note to all : go regexes are limited compared to many languages as they don't have backreferences or anything making their behavior hard to predict

Comment: This being said, I still don't understand the question :\

Comment: OP, maybe you could build a sample in [playground](http://play.golang.org/p/3VsQMI4Rx5) and precise what exact output you expect ?

Comment: I suspect the reason is that Go (presumably) also tries to match the longest possible sequence for a given pattern...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem could be that it's trying to do the longest match for the leftmost pattern.  If that's the case, try changing your original

`^(?P< one>.*)\\s(?P< two>.*):\\s(?P< three>.*)$`

```
here......^
```

to not permit a colon among those characters - `[^:]` if like regular sed regexes.  For safety's sake, if there may be more than two colons in a line, do that on the second part too.

`^(?P<one>[^:]*)\\s(?P<two>[^:]*):\\s(?P<three>.*)$`

Edit:
That seems to make the difference according to [this tester](http://regoio.herokuapp.com/), after changing the `\\s` to just `\s` and removing the original spaces in the pattern names.  Likewise [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/golang/index.html).